# Pandas iterating over the rows, creating dataframes for comparsion and calculating distance

Tags: python, pandas

```
family                drafted   IQ>120 Height>6.5 ShootPctg >0.4
James                  2019      1       1          1
Richardson             2019      1       1          0 
Embid                  2019      0       1          1
Curry                  2019      1       0          1
Ingram                 2018      0       1          0
Ball                   2019      1       0          1
James                  2018      0       0          0
McGrady                2018      1       1          1
Curry                  2017      1       0          0
Embid                  2016      1       1          0
Kidd                   2015      1       1          1
```

Let's assume that I have a dataframe like this which consists of basketball player names and their characteristics. In this imaginary dataset, a lot of players have their siblings playing in the same league but drafted in different years. I am interested in understanding how distinctive these players are compared to players in the previous drafts. However, the important point is that I don't wanna compare these players with their siblings. To do so,
first I create a vector of player characteristics:

```
df = df.assign(vector = df.iloc[:, -3:].values.tolist())
df['vector'] = df['vector'].apply(np.array)
```

Then I get:

```
family                drafted   IQ>120 Height>6.5 ShootPctg >0.4 vector
    James                  2019      1       1          1        [1, 1, 1]
    Richardson             2019      1       1          0        [1, 1, 0]
    Embid                  2019      0       1          1        [0, 1, 1]
    Curry                  2019      1       0          1        [1, 0, 1]
    Ingram                 2018      0       1          0        [0, 1, 0]
    Ball                   2019      1       0          1        [1, 0, 1]
    James                  2018      0       0          0        [0, 0, 0]
    McGrady                2018      1       1          1        [1, 1, 1]
    Curry                  2017      1       0          0        [1, 0, 0]
    Embid                  2016      1       1          0        [1, 1, 0]
    Kidd                   2015      1       1          1        [1, 1, 1]
```

Given that now I have a vector that summarizes player characteristics, I can simply compare the vector of each player with the players drafted in the previous year excluding their siblings and then take the average. 
Let's take James drafted 2019 as an example:
James's comparsion set will be all the players drafted before 2019, exluding his brother James drafted in 2018. Namely,

```
family                drafted   IQ>120 Height>6.5 ShootPctg >0.4 vector
    McGrady                2018      1       1          1        [1, 1, 1]
    Curry                  2017      1       0          0        [1, 0, 0]
    Embid                  2016      1       1          0        [1, 1, 0]
    Kidd                   2015      1       1          1        [1, 1, 1]
```

Then I want to compare James feature vector with player's listed above and take the average. Final output should be (note: I made up the number on dstnctv column):

```
family                drafted   IQ>120 Height>6.5 ShootPctg >0.4 dstnctv
        James                  2019      1       1          1     0.23
        Richardson             2019      1       1          0     0.12
        Embid                  2019      0       1          1     0.14
        Curry                  2019      1       0          1     0.23
        Ingram                 2018      0       1          0     0.12
        Ball                   2019      1       0          1     0.11
        James                  2018      0       0          0     0.09
        McGrady                2018      1       1          1     0.05
        Curry                  2017      1       0          0     0.11
        Embid                  2016      1       1          0     0.02
        Kidd                   2015      1       1          1     0.03
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I would like to add an extra row to the dataframe distinctiveness_index which tells how different is the game from the previous games on average

Comment: please add an expected output as dataframe as you have posted the input dataframe

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'weeklyyear'

Comment: @anky_91: I don2t think it is meaningful in my question, but ok.

Comment: for this table code returns `[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]` . Very informative :)))

Comment: as you wish then :)

Comment: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: @edyvedy13 How we can try to help if we can't know what you want to get?

Comment: Ok, let me make super simple.

Comment: @edyvedy13 but your code dors not return such result. Is it true?

Comment: It is very hard to produce a working example, but I am working on it

Comment: hope it is clearer now